# error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1 on pip install TA-Lib

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to instal TA-Lib in Mac Sierra with:

sudo pip install TA-Lib

But I'm getting this error:

```
 error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-bqV3xq/TA-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5HBbJo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-bqV3xq/TA-Lib/
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: add more lines from your output, the actually useful information is usually 3-4 lines up from where you've cut it off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installation instructions [from their github readme](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#dependencies) indicate that on macos you need the following:

```
brew install ta-lib
```